# WebChromeClient's onShowFileChooser not working with webview in android studio

Tags: android, webview

its a simple web app with a webview in it. and there is a farm with a button to select image from camera/album but with my current code its not working can anyone please help. here is my code

in **onCreate**

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("AndroidWebView");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    webView.loadUrl("URL");
```

then after this here is my **setWebChromeClient**

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                    String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            try {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File externalDataDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                File cameraDataDir = new File(externalDataDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "browser-photos");
                cameraDataDir.mkdirs();
                String mCameraFilePath = cameraDataDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFilePath));
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        mCapturedImageURI);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                        new Parcelable[] { cameraIntent });
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent,
                        FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera Exception:" + e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        // For Android < 3.0
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        // For Android > 4.1.1
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }

        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
            onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
            return true;
        }

        public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber,
                                     String sourceID) {
            Log.d("androidruntime", "www.example.com: " + message);
        }
    });
```

and **outside onCreate**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
            return;
        }
        Uri result = null;
        try {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                result = null;
            } else {
                result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent
                        .getData();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
}
```

in my other application this code was working fine but in this one it isnt working. when ever i press browse button from webview its does not do anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above api21, the method should be onShowFileChooser. If your device above LOLLIPOP, for sure your code won't work.

check out the doc here:
[onShowFileChooser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onShowFileChooser(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Candroid.net.Uri[]%3E,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams))

Comment: this answer is a demo for api above 21, check this out: [demo above api21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641683/android-studio-webview-not-calling-photo-gallery/48641903#48641903)